# What are differents between fillParentMaxWidth() and fillMaxWidth() in Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The following Code A is from the official sample [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/tree/main/AdvancedStateAndSideEffectsCodelab).

It seems that I get the same UI result after I replace the two `fillParentMaxWidth()` with `fillMaxWidth()`.

What are differents between `fillParentMaxWidth()` and `fillMaxWidth()` in Compose?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
private fun ExploreList(
    exploreList: List<ExploreModel>,
    onItemClicked: OnExploreItemClicked,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    listState: LazyListState = rememberLazyListState(),
) {
    LazyColumn(modifier = modifier, state = listState) {
        items(exploreList) { exploreItem ->
            Column(Modifier.fillParentMaxWidth()) {
                ExploreItem(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillParentMaxWidth(),
                    item = exploreItem,
                    onItemClicked = onItemClicked
                )
                Divider(color = crane_divider_color)
            }
        }
        item {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.navigationBarsHeight())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As here `LazyColumn` is used `fillParentMaxWidth` fill be same as `fillMaxWidth`.

In case of `LazyRow`, `fillMaxWidth` will raise an error. So `fillParentMaxWidth` can be used.

And the other way for `LazyColumn`.

Comment: Is there a reason it raises an error when that happens?